# Performance issue with pyqt6 block.setVisible

Tags: pyqt6

I have the following PoC code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QTextEdit,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import QTextBlockUserData
import sys
class UserData(QTextBlockUserData):
    """Store the Event information (line, timestamp, level) for each block."""

    def __init__(self, level=-1, line=-1, ts=-1):
        super(UserData, self).__init__()
        self.level = level
        self.line = line
        self.timestamp = ts

    def set_event_details(self, line, level, ts):
        """Set the Event information (line, timestamp, level)"""
        self.level = level
        self.line = line
        self.timestamp = ts
    def get_level(self):
        return UserData.level

    def get_timestamp(self):
        return UserData.timestamp

    def get_line(self):
        return UserData.line


class TextEditDemo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit")
        self.resize(600,800)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.btnPress1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.btnPress2 = QPushButton("Button 2")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        demo = [['2022.11.08 11: 54:01.270', 2,
                 'TLS:127.0.0.1:57655 SSL handshake ready.'],
                ['2022.11.08 11: 54:01.301', 1, 'Test'],
                ['2022.11.08 11: 54:01.301', 0,
                 'File corrupted'],
                ['2022.11.08 11: 54:01.302', 1,
                 'Test 2'],
                ['2022.11.08 11: 54:01.324', 2,
                 'thread exited.']]
        for i in range(1000):
            for item in demo:
                self.text_edit.append(item[0] +f' level {item[1]} ' + item[2])

        text_document = self.text_edit.document()
        for i in range(text_document.blockCount()):
            block = text_document.findBlockByNumber(i)
            temp = UserData()
            temp.set_event_details(i, demo[i%5][1], demo[i%5][0])
            block.setUserData(temp)

        self.btnPress1.clicked.connect(self.btnPress1_Clicked)
        self.btnPress2.clicked.connect(self.btnPress2_Clicked)

    def refresh_text_box(self):
        QApplication.processEvents()  # update gui for pyqt


    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        text_document = self.text_edit.document()
        for i in range(text_document.blockCount()):
            block = text_document.findBlockByNumber(i)
            if block.userData().level > 1:
                block.setVisible(False)
                text_document.markContentsDirty(block.position(), block.length())
            else:
                block.setVisible(True)
                text_document.markContentsDirty(block.position(), block.length())
        self.text_edit.update()



    def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
            text = ''
            text_document = self.text_edit.document()
            for i in range(text_document.blockCount()):
                block = text_document.findBlockByNumber(i)
                if block.userData().level <= 1:
                    text += block.text() + '\n'
            self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = TextEditDemo()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

In this example the two buttons do the same thing, but the plaintext copy is practically instant while the visibility is ~10 sec.

My main problem is that in the future there will be formatting in the text, so plaintext copy does not seem like a good idea.

The question is, what would be a reasonably efficient way of hiding \ removing the lines if there is formatting in play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are forcing the computation of the whole layout every time you call `markContentsDirty`.

It also doesn't make a lot of sense to do that for *all* blocks, and you should only do that whenever the visibility has actually changed.

Since you are probably going to layout again all the contents between the first (changed) block to the last, you should just mark contents dirty for the whole area contained between those blocks.

Using `findBlockByNumber` is also not a good choice, since you are actually iterating through all blocks, and you should instead use the internal iteration Qt already provides (using [`block.next()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblock.html#next)).

Here is a revised version of your code:

```py
    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        text_document = self.text_edit.document()
        block = text_document.begin()
        first = last = -1
        while block.isValid():
            if block.userData().level > 1:
                block.setVisible(False)
                if first < 0:
                    first = block.position()
                last = block.position() + block.length()
            elif not block.isVisible():
                block.setVisible(True)
                last = block.position() + block.length()
            block = block.next()
        if first >= 0:
            text_document.markContentsDirty(first, last - first)
```

Note that, unless you need special formatting, using QTextEdit is not a good choice: use QPlainTextEdit instead, which is specially optimized for *large* documents and provides better performances for their layouts.

Also note that I removed `self.text_edit.update()`, which was pointless for two reasons:

1. laying out again part of a document automatically schedules a redraw of the viewport, so that request would be ignored as redundant;
2. just like all scroll areas in Qt (classes inheriting from QAbstractScrollArea), if you need to redraw its contents you must call the `update()` (or `repaint()`) function on the *viewport*: the scroll area is just a container, and its viewport is set up in a way that it's *never* influenced by repaints of the parent; the only way to properly request an update on the contents of a scroll area, is to call the above functions on the viewport, for instance:

```py
    self.text_edit.viewport().update()
```

Comment: I have an addendum to the code you have shared, when you change the constant 1 to a variable and re-use it as a function, the elif not block.isVisible(): branch does not have first increased. 
If the function is used to only set visible, it does not mark the contents dirty